# triggering a function before $("").datepicker()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a `listeJNO` variable that I need in `beforeShowDay` function

```
$('#calendrier').datepicker({

                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                weekStart: 1,
                maxViewMode: 3,
                language: "fr",
                calendarWeeks: true,
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < listeJNO.length; i++) {
                        console.log(date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End);
                        if (date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End) {

                            return {

                                classes: 'morning-ferie'
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but before, I need to define the `listeJNO`. I have a function which is doing this actually its `getListeJNO()`. So here's my problem, wherever I put the `getListeJNO()` to initialize data in `listeJNO`, the `beforeShowDay` option inside the `$('calendrier').datepicker({...})` always goes first where `listeJNO` has no data inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to initialize the datepicker when the load of listeJNO is completed.
You could do this by returning a promise and set the datepicker in the "then" callback.

First create the promise which loads the data into the listeJNO

```
var listeJNO;
var loadListeJNOpromise = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
            //load the data into listeJNO, then send it in the resolve callback
            listeJNO = ....;
            
            resolve('Load completed'); // fulfilled
            
            //if something went wrong then reject it
            //reject('Didnt work..'); 
        }
    );
```

Then consume the promise as this

```
//create a function thats sets the datepicker
var initializeDatepicker = function(){
    $('#calendrier').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        weekStart: 1,
        maxViewMode: 3,
        language: "fr",
        calendarWeeks: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

            for (var i = 0; i < listeJNO.length; i++) {
                console.log(date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End);
                if (date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End) {

                    return {

                        classes: 'morning-ferie'
                    };
                }
            }
        }
};

//declare a function which invokes the datepicker function in the promise 
var initialize = function () {
    loadListeJNOpromise
        .then(function (fulfilled) {
            console.log(fulfilled);
            //call the datepicker initialize here
            initializeDatepicker();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
//invoke the initilize
initialize();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked ... And also, thank you for letting me know about "Promise"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and set the variable inside your `beforeShowDay`? I would think that would work. Have your `listeJNO` var declared outside the `beforeShowDay` function, and then set it inside that function. Something like this:

```
 beforeShowDay: function (date) {
               //Set your variable in this function
               listeJNO = getListeJNO();
                for (var i = 0; i < listeJNO.length; i++) {
                    console.log(date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End);
                    if (date >= listeJNO[i].Begin && date <= listeJNO[i].End) {

                        return {

                            classes: 'morning-ferie'
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: the problem is that listeJNO would be loaded everytime a day is about to show in the datepicker